# trouble maintaining the integrity of the data structure in a graph algorithm in a functional way

Tags: algorithm, scala, data-structures, functional-programming, depth-first-search

i'm trying to solve a problem from the UVA online judge site, specifically [539](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=645&page=show_problem&problem=480) where i need to use a DFS to find the longest path,  i can solve it  imperatively but i'd like to do it in a more functional idiomatic way using scala, the problem is that when the algorithm return from a branch the data structure is not updated for use in others branches, don't want to use vars, nor side effects, heres my code:

```
type Vertex=Int

type Graph = Map[Vertex,Set[Vertex]]

def DFS(start: Vertex, g: Graph): Int = {

  def loop(v: Vertex, visited: List[Vertex], size: Int = 0): Int = {

  val neighbours: List[Vertex] = ( g(v) filterNot visited.contains ).toList
   if (neighbours == Nil) size
   else {
  ( for (elem <- neighbours) yield loop(elem, v :: visited, size + 1) ).max }
    }
loop(start, List())
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to return `visited` along with your `max` and use `foldLeft` instead of `for` passing state to the next `loop` and returning it after fold.

Comment: Do you want something like foldLeft to pass along the modified `visited`? EDIT: Heh, @VictorMoroz, snap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the paths, not the Vertex in the visited Set (better performance than List in contains operation). Also you should try this starting in all the Vertex. Check this:

```
type Vertex = Int

type Graph = Map[Vertex, Set[Vertex]]

def DFS(g: Graph): Int = {

  def loop(current: Vertex, visited: Set[(Vertex, Vertex)]): Int = {
    val neighbours = g(current).filterNot(contains(visited, current, _))
    if (neighbours.isEmpty)
      visited.size
    else {
      (for {
        elem <- g(current).filterNot(contains(visited, current, _))
      } yield (loop(elem, add(visited, current, elem)))).max
    }
  }

  (for {
    elem <- g.keys
  } yield (loop(elem, Set()))).max
}

def add(set:Set[(Vertex,Vertex)], v1:Vertex, v2:Vertex): Set[(Vertex,Vertex)] =
  if(v1 < v2) add(set, v2,v1) else set.+((v1,v2))
def contains(set:Set[(Vertex,Vertex)], v1:Vertex, v2:Vertex):Boolean =
  if(v1 < v2) contains(set, v2,v1) else set.contains((v1,v2))
```